# update tkinter without any button moved

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

Before Update:
[image: Before Update]
After update:
[image: After Update]

My code for the update:

```
def plot(data,the_main):
    fig = Figure(figsize=(5,5),dpi=100)
    plot1 = fig.add_subplot()
    plot1.plot(data)

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master = the_main)   
    canvas.draw() 
  
    # placing the canvas on the Tkinter window 
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=5,column=6)
  
    # creating the Matplotlib toolbar 
    # toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas,the_main) 
    # toolbar.update()
```

My code before accessing the update(it's related cause the window):

```
def buttons_for_month(country):
    the_button = tkinter.Tk()
    the_button.title(country)
    the_button.geometry('967x590')
    month_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] 
    columns = 0
    for i in range(0,len(month_list)):
        name = "button",i
        name = tkinter.Button(master = the_button,
                             command = lambda: plot([1,2,3,4,5],the_button),
                             height = 2,
                             width=10,
                             text=month_list[i])
        name.grid(row=0,column=columns)
        columns += 1
```

I'm trying to embedding `matplotlib` into `tkinter`
It's working , but not as i expected.
I've tried just make a new window  , special for the graph ..However , 
My desktop screen were a messed.

> so my question:
>  How to manipulate my code to make `matplotlib` embedded into `tkinter` while
> keep the `button(s)` at their places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't run your code, but I'm guessing this will do it:

```
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=5,column=6, columnspan=7)
```

The reason this works is because you are putting the plot inside a single column. Every column has a uniform width so it forces column 6 to be as wide as the plot. By having the plot span multiple columns, it prevents the single column from having to be resized to fit the entire plot.

Arguably, an even better solution is to put your buttons in a frame, pack that frame at the top, and then pack the plot below it. `grid` is very useful when creating a matrix of widgets, but in your case you're not doing that.

Comment: oh yeah , it did works...it seem like `html` sorta but how do you know?..i've search the documentation for `tkinter .grid()` and not found anything useful for me